# getDrawingCache() returns a bitmap with dimensions of -1

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-view

As the title says, the getDrawingCache function returns a bitmap with both width and height set to -1. I saw several posts about the function returning null, but not dimensions of -1.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok now. The problem was something with my coordinate translation...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you call `view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` after creating the layout, and call `view.buildDrawingCache();` right before getting the cache.